# Big(O) notation

Tags: python, performance, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

```
def largest_34(a:list):

    a.sort()
    m1, m2, m3, m4 = a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0]

    for i in a[4:]:
        if i > m1:
            m4 = m3
            m3 = m2
            m2 = m1
            m1 = i           

    return m3+m4
```

## 2

```
def largest_third(a:list):

    n = len(a)//3
    a.sort()
    a.reverse()
    sum_n = 0

    for i in range(n):
        sum_n += a[i]

    return sum_n
```

## 3

```
def third_at_least(a:list):
    L2 = []
    a.sort()
    MatchNum = (len(a)//3 + 1)
    Return_Val_in_List = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (i == len(a)-1):
            CountNum = (a[i], a.count(a[i]))
            L2.append(CountNum)     

        elif a[i] != a[i+1] and i != (len(a)-1):
            CountNum = (a[i], a.count(a[i]))
            L2.append(CountNum)

    for j in range(len(L2)):
        if L2[j][1] >= MatchNum:
                Return_Val_in_List.append(L2[j][0])

    if Return_Val_in_List == []:
        return None
    else:
        return Return_Val_in_List
```

I'm learning big-O notation. I'm hoping to get the correct answers for the codes above. So, for the first question, I think it's `nlog(n)` since it has `a.sort()`, which is `nlog(n)` and the for loop, which is `n`. My answer for this questions is `n+nlog(n)`. Since such small numbers are abandoned, I would say it's `nlog(n)`

For question2, I would say it's also `n+log(n)` (`nlog(n)` from `a.sort` and `n` from for loop). Therefore, the final answer is same as Q1. `nlog(n)`

For question3, I would say it's `nlog(n)+2n` (`nlog(n)` from `a.sort` and `2n` from for loops).

Can I take this logic? If not, could anyone possibly explain how to analyse those code?

Comment: For question 2, `a.reverse()` has a time complexity of `O(n)`.  It would not effect the final answer, but just something to realize.

Comment: `a.sort()` then `a.reverse()` is dumb. Better do: `a.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: `nlog(n)+2n` is `n*(log(n)+2)` hence `O(nlog(n))`. It maybe slower, but the ratio is the same: computation time increases the same way when n increases.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wouldn't call it dumb, as `a.sort(reverse=True)` does do **two** reversals (one before and one after sorting), so it can be *faster* to do `a.sort()` and `a.reverse()`.